# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver while running spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, spark-submit

**Spark version : 2.3.0**

I am running **spark-submit** command with `--jars` option.

I have already provided ***ojdbc6.jar*** in the command as shown below.

**Command**

```
./spark-submit --class com.sample.ABC --jars /scratch/user/abc/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar --master spark://IP:Port "/scratch/user/abc/POC jar/ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Still I am getting below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$7.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:85)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
        at com.sample.Transformation.main(Transformation.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added `--driver-class-path` to the command as shown below :

```
./spark-submit --class com.sample.ABC --jars /scratch/user/abc/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar `--driver-class-path /scratch/user/abc/drools-jars/ojdbc6.jar --master spark://IP:Port "/scratch/user/abc/POC jar/ABC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

This resolved the issue.